# SwiftUI: PreferenceKey is not called when parent view is embedded in NavigationView

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview, vertical-alignment, geometryreader

`DynamicScalingView` is a child view with two buttons designed to have equal width & height using `preferencekey`

**Issue:** When `DynamicScalingView` is embedded in NavigationView it not longer adapts to `intrinsic` and increases its frame size. Current implementation without Navigation works fine but would like to understand how to fix this issue when embedded in `NavigationView`

- Uncomment NavigationView in sample view to reproduce the issue
- `DynamicScalingView` should adapt to Dynamic font size and increase its frame size maintaining equal width & height constraint between the buttons.

XCode 12.2 and iOS 14.2

```
struct SampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gr in
            //NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        // fills whatever space is left
                        Spacer()
                            .foregroundColor(.clear)

                        // view should fit with intrinsic content size
                        DynamicScalingView()
                            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                            .border(Color.blue, width: 1)
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                    .border(Color.red, width: 1)
                    .frame(minHeight: gr.size.height)
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                }
        //  }
        }
    }

    struct DynamicScalingView: View {
        @State private var labelHeight = CGFloat.zero

        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Text("Some Text Some Text Some Text")
                        .padding(.horizontal, 2)
                })
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(minHeight: labelHeight)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .background(GeometryReader {
                        Color.clear
                            .preference(
                                key: ViewHeightKey.self,
                                value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height
                            )
                    })

                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Text("Some Text")
                        .padding(.horizontal, 2)
                })
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(minHeight: labelHeight)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .background(GeometryReader {
                        Color.clear
                            .preference(
                                key: ViewHeightKey.self,
                                value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height
                            )
                    })
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) {
                self.labelHeight = $0
            }
        }
    }

    struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
        static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
        static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
            value = max(value, nextValue())
        }
    }
}
```