# Make two buttons equal height and width in HStack

Tags: swift, swiftui, vstack, hstack

I have one VStack and another HStack with buttons inside. I faced problem with shrinking buttons based on their content even though I tried to set fixed width and height of Buttons.

Here is the main screen:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUINavigator

struct SurveyScreenView: View, IItemView {
    
    var listener: INavigationContainer?
    @State var survey: Survey
    @State var isUp = false
    @State var isDown = false
    
    @State var widthButton: CGFloat = 100
    @State var heightButton: CGFloat = 50
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 32) {
                Text(survey.title)
                    .font(.title)
                Text(survey.description)
                
                VoteView( survey: $survey, isUp: $isUp, isDown: $isDown)
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                Button(action: {
                    listener?.pop()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Feed")
                })
            )
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Survey"))
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

View with Buttons in HStack

```
struct VoteView: View {
    
    @Binding var survey: Survey
    @Binding var isUp: Bool
    @Binding var isDown: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 64) {
            
            VoteButton (
                isVoted: $isUp,
                counter: survey.upVotes,
                text: "YES"
            ) {
                self.isUp.toggle()
                if isUp == isDown {
                    self.isDown.toggle()
                }
            }
            
            VoteButton (
                isVoted: $isDown,
                counter: survey.downVotes,
                text: "NO"
            ) {
                self.isDown.toggle()
                if isUp == isDown {
                    self.isUp.toggle()
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Cutom button view

```
struct VoteButton: View {
    
    @Binding var isVoted: Bool
    var counter: Int = 0
    var text: String = ""
    var clicked: (() -> Void)

    var body: some View {
        if isVoted {
            Button(action: clicked) {
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
                    Text(text)
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text("\(counter)")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(.blue)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40)
            }
            
        } else {
            Button(action: clicked)  {
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
                    Text(text)
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text("\(counter)")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .background(.white)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried several tutorials, for [example](https://betterprogramming.pub/swiftui-tutorial-working-with-stacks-vstack-hstack-and-zstack-2b0070be18d7). Also tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607172/swiftui-hstack-elements-with-equal-height).

I got the same result everywhere, like this one:
[image: bad]

But I am actually expecting this result:
[image: good]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` for to stretch any view.

```
struct VoteButton: View {

@Binding var isVoted: Bool
var counter: Int = 0
var text: String = ""
var clicked: (() -> Void)

var body: some View {
    if isVoted {
        Button(action: clicked) {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
                Text(text)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)  <<<<-- This shall fix your issue
                Text("\(counter)")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)  <<<<-- This shall fix your issue
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(.blue)
            .cornerRadius(8)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

    } else {
        Button(action: clicked)  {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
                Text(text)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)  <<<<-- This shall fix your issue

                Text("\(counter)")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)  <<<<-- This shall fix your issue

            }
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .background(.white)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2))
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: haven't got any change

Comment: Updated now, problem was your Texts were not stretched.

Answer (score 5):

You can try below code technique and modify it according to requirements

```
HStack {
            Button("Yes") { }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.red)
                .clipShape(Capsule())

            Button("No") { }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.red)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
        }
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        .padding()
```

[image]

Comment: not working as well

Comment: when I scanned this I thought "I already did this!" but actually I did `frame(width: .infinity)` which doesn't work but `maxWidth` does. Thank you