# Make a View the same size as another View which has a dynamic size in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I want to achieve this (For the screenshots I used constant heights, just to visualize what I am looking for):

[image: Goal (1)]   [image: Goal (1)]

The two `Views` containing text should together have the same height as the (blue) `Image` View. The right and left side should also be of the same width. The important part: The `Image` View can have different aspect ratios, so I can't set a fixed height for the parent View. I tried to use a `GeometryReader`, but without success, because when I use `geometry.size.height` as height, it takes up the whole screen height.

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                HStack {
                    Image("blue-test-image")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    VStack {
                        Text("Some Text")
                            .padding()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                            .background(Color.gray)
                        Text("Other Text")
                            .padding()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                            .background(Color.gray)
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: geometry.size.height /* should instead be the height of the Image View */)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of what my code leads to:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62451599/12299030?

Comment: As I can see in your photos, you already fixed the issue, so what you looking for more?

Comment: @swiftPunk for the photos I just used fixed heights to show what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks, that hasn't worked for me yet, because (I think) the Image doesn't fire a `onPreferenceChange` event. I would have to do it e.g. in `onAppear`, but I don't know how to access its height then.

Comment: @Steffen: Your question is not clear! As I see in your code you did not used any hard coded value! And You already have what you want. So what is the point of your question?

Comment: @Steffen if you are still having problems with the `PreferenceKeys` put up a new question with your code and we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I solved it in this case:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestScreen: View {
    @State private var imageHeight = CGFloat.zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image("blue-test-image")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(GeometryReader {
                        Color.clear.preference(
                            key: ViewHeightKeyTestScreen.self,
                            value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height
                        )
                    })
                VStack {
                    Text("Some Text")
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .background(Color.gray)
                    Text("Other Text")
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .background(Color.gray)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: self.imageHeight, maxHeight: self.imageHeight)
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKeyTestScreen.self) {
                self.imageHeight = $0
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ViewHeightKeyTestScreen: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}

struct TestScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestScreen()
    }
}
```